# Paneling barplot from pivot table

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, bar-chart

I have a table like this:

```
ID var1. var2. var3. var4. var5. var6. var7 var8 var9 ... var22 ...
A.  1.   1.    7.    0.     0.6.   0.   7.  2.    2,4.   ....
B   9.   1.    7.    0.     0.6.   0.   7.  2.    2,4.   ....
C   0.   1.    0.    8.     0.5.   5.   7.  2.9.  2,8.   ....
```

And I want to build a bar plot for each ID and bind them all on a panel, my idea of panel is like [here](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Images/bar_11_lg.png).
So, 'x' will be the variables (that are columns names) and the 'y' the values that are the values of the columns in this data frame.

One important thing is that I **don't want** to show on the graph the variables that have *zero value for a given ID*, so, for example: for ID 'A', var4 and var6 won't be on the graph of ID 'A', but they will be on the graph of ID 'C', for example.

So far I have:

The transposition of the columns:

```
df_melted = res.melt(id_vars='ID')
```

Then I remove all the zeros:

```
df_melted_no_zeros = df_melted[df_melted.value != 0]
```

Then as I could not manage to build the panel, I filter by one ID:

```
ID_A = df_melted_no_zeros[(df_melted_no_zeros.ID == "A")]
```

Then on the plot that are so many variables and I can't find how can I put them on a plot to be readable, since there are so many names (like 20 for each graph on the x axis).  For me it will work to show just the legend of top 5 values, but I couldn't manage how to do it. 
Als my variables are mostly between 0.004 and 0.009 but then there are always two variables that are value 4 or 5, so the rest is like irrelevant on the plot.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
variables = ID_A['variable']
values = ID_A['value']
ax.bar(variables,values)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I tried for some quite time before asking... But I could not manage. If I manage how to do it I won't be here asking

Comment: The help provided here can be *much* more effective if you share *what* you tried; you might have been quite close to success!

Comment: Ah ok! In my last question, I shared what I did and they didn't like it because I was too close of the answer and it was something they said it was for my specific case and asked me to remove the question, so I tried to leave it more general here. But I will edit with what I tried then!

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking about "0.004 ... 4 or 5" stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this subset of your DataFrame:

```
ID var1. var2. var3. var4. var5. var6. var7 var8 var9
A.  1.   1.    7.    0.     0.6   0.   7.  2.    2.4
B   9.   1.    7.    0.     0.6   0.   7.  2.    2.4
C   0.   1.    0.    8.     0.    5.   7.  2.9   2.8
```

From wide to long:

```
df_melted = df.melt(id_vars='ID')
```

Get just top several:

```
df_top5 = df_melted[df_melted['value'].isin(
                    df_melted.groupby('ID')['value'].nlargest(5).unique())]
```

Plot with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(df_top5,col="ID",sharex=False,sharey=False,col_wrap=2)
g.map(sns.barplot,'variable','value',order=None,hue=df_top5['variable'],
      dodge=False,palette='deep')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering :) Can you explain me this line? f_melted['var'] = df_melted['variable'].str.extract('(\d+)')[0] I am getting NAN when I run this. In my dataset the variables do not start with "var" all equal, it was just an example, i don't know if can be this the problem...

Comment: Also I could not see where you remove the 0 values. The ones with zero value are still showing with value 0. I don't want them o be on the graph, as I wrote on the question because they are too many if I got them all

Comment: In fact I don't have 0 nor 'var', I have things like 'account', 'cases', 'discovery' etc

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira: please see edited answer. I think this is closer to what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you!! A follow up question, I tried to put hue='variable', so the variables that are equal in different plots will have the same color, but then I got stacked bar plots. Do you have any idea of why? :)

Comment: I tried with order=sorted(df_top5['variable']) but then I got again the blank spaces on the graph :(

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira: I edited the answer with fixed hue.